# Wire up the winform close button and a button on my form

Tags: winforms

I have a "save changes" button on my form that does some cleanup on the way out ( writing results to a file, etc) and then closes the app.  I also have the form close button ( the x button ).  I want the cleanup to happen if the person exits via the close button or thru my save changes button.  If I use the form_closing event, it is being called recursively.  This should be darn straighforward, but I'm missing something.  Any help?

Comment: Post code then only we can see what you're doing wrong. If you can't share code just mock it

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Form_Closing vs Form_Closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the save code into its own Save() method.  Call that Save() method in your FormClosing() event.  Finally, simply close the form in the Button handler using `this.Close();` or `Me.Close()`, depending on your .Net language.